# Can you build multiple layouts with twitter bootstrap based on window size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Maybe this is a very simple question, but I am wondering if you can setup *multiple* layouts based on window size, and have them apply based off the users current window size?

Right now I use bootstrap with C# and I set one standard size like `col-md-#`, and then let everything below that just fall apart into pieces as elements start overlapping. This makes the site at least readable on small screens but it is still a mess since everything is all broken apart.

**Example md/lg layout**

[image]

**moving to a smaller screen (sm/xs) then breaks those elements into pieces, which cascade vertically.**

[image]

What I am wondering is if I can maybe setup a `col-xs/sm-12`, and then re-arrange the elements (or re-size items like images/tables/divs) to better suite a smaller screen. Basically have/display different layouts when moving from different screen sizes.

**Is it possible that instead of just breaking the elements apart (like above) for smaller screens, to in fact run a different style for smaller screen sizes (below)?**

[image]

TLDR: Does bootstrap currently support multiple layouts that are determined by window size, rather than having just one layout, and breaking everything apart for anything smaller?

If so, can a simple example be given showing two layouts being enacted by different window sizes.

Comment: ? I don't get the question .... Why don't use the values for col-xs-6 for example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

If your using bootstrap 3, you can simply define the layout for xs, which will then scale up until something bigger takes over.

for example

```
col-xs-6 col-md-12
col-xs-6 col-md-12
col-xs-12
col-xs-12
```

So when its on xs, it will display as 6 columns, then medium up will display on 12 columns.

The above is better described here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

you can also use push/pull to adjust the ordering http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

Comment: So is `col-xs-6 col-md-12` saying: when on a `md`+ show this element as grid size of 12, while if it is at `sm` break the elements, and when it hits `xs` make it a grid size 6? If not, then I confused haha

Comment: almost, it works mobile/smallest first. So when you say `xs`, that will apply the columns to EVERYTHING, Until it hits something bigger. So if you did `col-xs-12 col-md-6`. both `xs` and `sm` will be `12`. then `md, lg, xl etc`, will be `6`. Is that any clearer?

Comment: Okay that makes sense. So on top of this, I guess I am looking for a way to almost separately display an element like a `div`. As in lets say I had TWO divs, one that that is re-arranged internally to look nicer on smaller sizes, and one that is re-arranged to look nicer on large screens. Is there a way to say in the `class` of the `div`s to display its div if screen size is md/lg, otherwise hide it, and visa verse for smaller screens? Basically let bootstrap handle the showing/hiding of elements on top of grid re-sizing for a better viewing.

Comment: Yup, its all listed on their css page -> http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities